# Перебор массива foreach или for в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем косяк у меня при переборе массива:

Есть коллекция с Меню:

Так же есть связи к категориям:

Мне нужно сделать массив :

> ['menu.name' => ['category_id' => 'name']]

Вот мой код:

```
$menus = Menu::with('category')->get();
        $array = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($menus);$i++){
                for ($g = 0; $g < count($menus[$i]->category);$g++){
                    $array[$menus[$i]->name]->push([$menus[$i]->category[$g]->id => $menus[$i]->category[$g]->name]);
                }
            }
        dd($array);
```

В итоге получается вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. в TEST-1 он должен вывести 2 значения, а он выводит одно, значение получается перезаписывается, а как вот по порядку вывести дальше не понимаю.
по идеи в TEST-1 должно быть вот так:

> ['TEST-1' => ['1' => '1','5' => '1.1']]

Comment: Оформите код с помощью кнопки "{}" в местном редакторе. А то трудно перепечатывать с картинки.

Comment: Изменил ответ. Попробуйте и расскажите, что получилось.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вот третий вариант. Ещё раз исправленный.

Comment: Спасибо Огромное, теперь все работает как должно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$menus = Menu::with('category')->get();
$array = array();

foreach($menus as $m){
    foreach($m->category as $c){
        $array[$m->name][$с->id] = $с->name;
    }

}
dd($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Юрий, не надо останавливаться на полпути. Давайте используем **ВСЮ МОЩЬ** коллекций Laravel

```
$menus = Menu::with('category')->get();
$array = $menus->keyBy('name')->map(function ($m, $key) {
    return $m->category->pluck('name', 'id');;
})->all();
dd($array);
```

Comment: Была у меня мысль, но я постеснялся :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом `pluck()`:

```
$menus = Menu::with('category')->get();
$array = array();

foreach($menus as $m){
    $categories = $m->category->pluck('name', 'id');
    $array[$m->name] = $сategories->all();
}
dd($array);
```